# Why my uploaded theme on Liferay server doesn't work

Tags: liferay

I have created some theme in Liferay. Then I exported it as a *.war file. My next step was to install it on liferay server and then run. But this theme doesn't work, it is unavailable. Do you know why?
Aditional information ... same I did with some portlets and it works. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you exporting instead of running ant command or maven command to deploy it?

Comment: Because I am a beginner and I didnt know there is another way of how to do it :-) ... OK ... I I am going to try it

Comment: Once your theme is deployed properly you will able to see the message, 1-theme is available for use.once theme is deployed go to site administration and apply your theme for the pages you want.